# C static tests called on construct

Tags: c, testing

I have created a small program mirroring my source code.  Here main, when in debug mode, calls external library tester functions before it runs the main app.  Imagine the constructor function in that library allocates memory and when in debug also tests some static functions. If that library is tested, it runs static tester code.  If that library is used, static tester code.  the ***static testers run every time the library function is called***.

> main.c

```
// calls test and library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// to test if the lib is there and the function does what it says claims
extern int testExternalLibFunctions(void);

#include "lib.h"

int main(){
    testExternalLibFunctions();

    printf("main function uses doTheTango\n");
    doTheTango();

    // do the magic stuff here and
    doTheTango();

    return 0;
}
```

> test_lib.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "lib.h"

static int Static_doTheTangoTest();

int testExternalLibFunctions(){
    // define DO_THE_TANGO_TEST_SELF_TRUE
    Static_doTheTangoTest();
    // undefine DO_THE_TANGO_TEST_SELF_TRUE
    return 0;
}

int Static_doTheTangoTest(){
    printf("external function tester calls doTheTango\n");
    doTheTango();
    return 0;
}
```

> lib.h

```
#ifndef DO_THE_TANGO_HEADER
#define DO_THE_TANGO_HEADER

extern int doTheTango();

#endif // DO_THE_TANGO_HEADER
```

> lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "lib.h" //self 
// ONLY HERE SHOULD STATIC FUNCTIONS BE TESTED

static int STATIC_TEST();

int doTheTango(){
    printf("Dancing is fun - ");
    // if defined DO_THE_TANGO_TEST_SELF_TRUE
    STATIC_TEST();
    // endif
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int STATIC_TEST(){
    printf("Static test 1, Yet again!");
    return 0;
}
```

It is not the intention to split tester and main function, because the main is calling more testers, etc ... they are inter-dependant!

How can I make the library do the static tests only when first included?  Something like in python, where you test

`if(__name__ == __main__) -> do the static tests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working! and actually also what I was looking for!

```
// in the global doTheTangoTest you define:
extern int TEST_TANGO_SELF;

doTheTangoTest{
    // to set it to 1 if the library is testing itself
    TEST_TANGO_SELF = 1;
    doTheTango();
    // to set it to 0 if testing itself is finished
    TEST_TANGO_SELF = 0;
}
```

and in doTheTango source

```
// you define again, but not as extern this time, just as int
int TEST_TANGO_SELF;

int doTheTango(){
    printf("Dancing is fun - ");
    // and use this global variable in a simple if statement
    if(TEST_TANGO_SELF){
        STATIC_TEST();
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because this is a preprocessor directive. Your code is processed by 1) the preprocessor, 2) the compiler and 3) the linker. The preprocessor is just a dumb tool for creating macros and filtering stuff before it is sent to the compiler. In this case, the definition  TEST_SELF_TRUE is only seen in the .file where it is defined. Preprocessor directives are not variable declarations! You can find much info on the preprocessor on the internet.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the idea was more on how can I change this pre-processor directive into something I can use that works a bit the same?

Comment: Instead of a global , you could use `static int TEST_TANGO_SELF` inside the function. Generally speaking, global names should be avoided if there's an easy alternative

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. I see from the source code that you say "Static test 1, Yet again!", so I assume you don't want the STATIC_TEST to be called on subsequent calls to doTheTango.

If this is what you want, then do:

```
int doTheTango(){
    static int isTested = 0;
    printf("Dancing is fun - ");
    if (!isTested) {
        isTested = 1;
        STATIC_TEST();
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not what I meant.  This isTested variable is local and scope goes away when stack is cleared. -- I am looking more in direction of: "if self Library is tested, do the static tests".  I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: No it doesn't. It is static. Local scope but not on stack.

Comment: @mattiash Given the vagueness of the "real" STATIC_TEST definition, I'd move _isTested = 1_ above the call to prevent a roundabout recursive double invocation (e.g. we don't want STATIC_TEST -> STATIC_TEST2 -> ... -> doTheTango)

Comment: So I am basically looking for a defined variable in the Static_doTheTangoTest where it states, we are testing our own library, I have capitalise that comment in code above, how do you do that?

Comment: I think I need further information. What kind of tests are in the test_lib.c? Unit tests?

Comment: solution was in declaring global variable, unfortunately.  I will include the solution in previous post or update answer #2